# Is there any way to trade without photo id before Bisq introduces its API?

Tags: exchanges, decentralization, exchange-software, decentralized-exchanges

I know that the Bisq developers are "working on it", but v1.5 was just released today and still not a sign of it. I'm growing ever more impatient.

While I like Bisq, and understand that it takes time to develop sensitive things like this, it would still feel better if there were at least one alternative. But there isn't, as far as I know. I don't mean "fake-decentralized" websites which are fully centralized. I mean decentralized applications for trading Bitcoin, supporting automation.

I'd like to try (with a very small amount of BTC) to trade it against other crypto currencies in an automated manner. Sadly, all exchanges require photo id BS, so they cannot be used.

What happens if Bisq is shut down? I depend entirely on it; there's literally no other way for me to get Bitcoin. If it goes down, I go down.

And no, the fact that it's a decentralized application doesn't stop somebody from nuking their official, centralized, clearnet website, or the GitHub repository. Obviously, they wouldn't rely on these if they had a practical choice, but nobody uses these "alternative Internet" projects.

It's weird to me that Bisq appears to be one-of-a-kind rather than one out of many different decentralized exchanges. How can that be?